# SSIS -- Reading tags in Rowset and storing in table

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a unique problem. I am using SSIS to load multiple files and in the ROWSET i have the file name and RowCount. How can i store in an my ETL Log table with 
Package ID - SRC_FILE_NM - Rows Read -

I am reading multiple files in same package.

```
<ROWSET xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SRC_FILE_NM>tauth_type_fullext_2018-10-08_11-32-07.312.xml</SRC_FILE_NM>
    <RECORDCOUNT>2</RECORDCOUNT>
    <ROW>  <AUTH_TYPE_CDE>LCL</AUTH_TYPE_CDE>  <AUTH_TYPE_DESC>Local</AUTH_TYPE_DESC> </ROW>
    <ROW>  <AUTH_TYPE_CDE>GLB</AUTH_TYPE_CDE>  <AUTH_TYPE_DESC>Global</AUTH_TYPE_DESC> </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: So are you reading from an xml file? How are you processing the `<ROW>` data to insert it into the db table? Do you want to add the `<SRC_FILE_NM>` and `<RECORDCOUNT>' to each ro of the rowset, or do you want to insert just these two values into a log table?

Comment: I can give you an answer with a script task in C# but I am interested on how these guys answer with SSIS objects

Comment: i want to store the xml data in the target table which has same structure as xml but   i want to store the two tags coming in the rowset ( not coming in xml itself) in a log table where i will have package name , src file name (coming in xml rowset) , src row count ( coming in xml) and target row count calculated during loading. I have 10 tables per package each has a an xml and corresponding target table so 10 xml source and and 10 target tables per package

Answer (score 0):

script component answer:

Add these 2 namespaces up top

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Above  CreateNewOutputRows() place the following to define your XML. I pasted your sample into https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to get this converted.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ROW")]
public class ROW
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AUTH_TYPE_CDE")]
    public string AUTH_TYPE_CDE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AUTH_TYPE_DESC")]
    public string AUTH_TYPE_DESC { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ROWSET")]
public class ROWSET
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SRC_FILE_NM")]
    public string SRC_FILE_NM { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RECORDCOUNT")]
    public int RECORDCOUNT { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ROW")]
    public List<ROW> ROW { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
}
```

This is your code to read the xml in your output rows:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    string filePath = ""; //put your filepath here. The best way is from a variable in SSIS. Also best since you need a foreach loop to get all the files you are processing.
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);

    ROWSET xml;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ROWSET));
    xml = (ROWSET)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
    sr.Close(); //So important, otherwise you can't move file to processed

    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.fname = xml.SRC_FILE_NM;
    Output0Buffer.rc = xml.RECORDCOUNT;
    //Note you can get everything at this point but you didn't ask for it.
}
```

Comment: You will need to define your output in Script Component GUI and assign data types. I chose fname and rc as column names

Comment: i will see how can i use it . I have never used C sharp before in my life

Comment: It's tougher to write it than read it. I did the whole thing for you. C# will greatly expand what you can do with ssis